# Graphviz: Given a tree render nodes with maximum path length from root in the same layer?

Tags: graphviz

The build system I'm using (github) renders graphs of build steps where steps with the same maximum path length from the root node are drawn as a layer. I'm jealous of this, because I think it may make complicated dependency graphs easier to read.

Is there a way of getting graphviz to output this.

It ends up looking something like this:

```
Root
|    \
C1    C2
|      /  \
C3    C4   C5
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
graph {
  node[shape=plaintext]
  Root -- C1
  C1 -- C3
  Root -- C2
  C2 -- C4
  C2 -- C5
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Probably not... but now I need to create a counterexample :p